# How may I create an Generic class Enum<K> which extends EnumMap and call super( K.class )?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, constructor, enums

G'day, I was aiming to create an abstract (base) class by **extend**-ing `EnumMap`.  I already have existing prototype code that works great based on an `EnumMap` sub-class and I want to convert that into a generic base that I can use with different Enum-types (i.e. generic `Enum<K>`).

The road-block I struck is ...

- How to tell the `EnumMap` constructor the class of the generic `Enum<K>`?

For comparison the working (non-generic) class look like the following, given the `Enum<States>`:

```
    public class    MyMap extends EnumMap<States, FocusTraversalPolicy>
    {
        private static  States  DEFAULT_POLICY;
        private static  States  currentPolicy   = DEFAULT_FLOW;

        public MyMap (){
            this( States.DATA_INPUT );
        }

        public MyMap ( final ProcessState defaultPolicy  ){

            super(States.class );

            DEFAULT_POLICY = defaultPolicy;
            currentPolicy  = DEFAULT_FLOW;
        }
    }
```

My ability to translate this into a generic version has hit a set of alternative errors which boils down to a difficulty passing the Enum type (`K.class`) to the EnumMap's parent constructor, viz.

```
Cannot select from type variable
```

and (*briefly*)

```
No suitable constructor found ... 
argument mismatch; Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<K>)
```

My declaration *so far* looks like this:

```
    public abstract class MapBase<K> extends EnumMap<K, FocusTraversalPolicy>{

        private  K  DEFAULT_POLICY;
        private  K  currentPolicy;

        private Enum Dummy {
            NOTHING
        }

        private MapBase() {      //  disable empty constructor
            this(Dummy.NOTHING); //  Exclude NullPointerException-s
        }

        public MapBase( final K defaultPolicy ) // Default compulsory
        {
            super( K.class );                   //  <-- Cannot select from type variable
                                                //  OR
            super( defaultPolicy.getClass() );  //  <-- No suitable constructor found

            DEFAULT_POLICY = defaultPolicy;
            currentPolicy  = DEFAULT_FLOW;
        }
    }
```

This is as far as I got.  I attempted a few variations with more or less different ways to tell me the same thing, e.g.

```
    class MapBase<K extends Enum<K>> 
        extends EnumMap<K, FocusTraversalPolicy>{
            :
   }
```

While a generics version for the base class is the Most desirable, it seems that this may not be possible; or that I am not following the right syntax to making the '*kind of*' base-class I want.

Even knowing if, "*You can't do that.*" Is helpful and I'll divert my efforts to a different structure.  It just seems more OO to `inherit` versus re-inventing a perfectly good existing *prototype wheel*.  My thanks in advance.

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please pay attention to the preview when editing, and review the post after saving.

Comment: This looks seriously wrong: extending EnumMap insted of using one (i.e. delegating to EnumMap), capitalizing a non-final field in all-caps, initializing a static field from a constructor, trying tostore an instance of Dummy into a variable of type K. Forget about your desired design for a while, and tell us what are you trying to achieve, because there's probably a better way.

Comment: What about composition over inheritance?

Comment: While I might be forced to use `Composition` or `Delegation` or some alternative method to write MORE code to achieve what I am doing in once instance _today_ ... I feel they are moot responses; because I _may_ and I can do this with C# or C++ and the question is "How may" this be done.

Comment: @JBNizet ... That may be a fair comment in your personal or peer group without citing the complete requirement.  First and foremost the largest benefit of Object Oriented design in my experience is keeping things DRY (Do-not Repeat Yourself).  The Java code is merely for illustration, and to highlight germane points.  (It is like the pre-thinking of a pseudo-code thought-bubble)

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. The only difference between the two declarations of `MapBase` above are that the second one's `K` has the bound `extends Enum<K>`. Is your question why that bound is necessary? You can see why by looking at [`EnumMap`'s declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). The first type parameter of `EnumMap` is declared `K extends Enum<K>`. Since your `K` is used as the first type argument for `EnumMap`, it must extend `Enum<K>`, or it won't satisfy `EnumMap`'s requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The glaring problem with the code is the apparent inappropriate use of inheritance. You're unlikely to save much memory, and the code becomes a mess.

So the start of the class becomes

```
public class TraversalPolicies<K extends Enum<K>> {
    private final Map<K, FocusTraversalPolicy> policies;
```

The constructor for `EnumMap` needs the `Class` of the enum because it is going to do something funky indexing the ordinal into an array of values.

The straightforward was of doing this is having the `Class` object passed to your generic class.

```
    public TraversalPolicies(Class<K> clazz) {
        this.policies = new EnumMap<>(clazz);
```

Alternatively, the `Class` can be taken from an instance of the enum if you have one available.

```
    public TraversalPolicies(K defaultPolicy) {
        this.policies = new EnumMap<>(defaultPolicy.getDeclaringClass());
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, ta. But the policy is not of type-<Enum K>.  The requirement is to MAP different enum values to policies.  That code is running, it is Very Simple and tested.  It is desirable to make the base code _generic_ (small g).  That was _all_.

Comment: I don't follow. Your code had policy variables having type `K` which was used as key for an `EnumMap` so should have been declared as `K extends Enum<K>`. The reduction of source code size using opportunistic inheritance is tiny and not worth the mess it creates.

Comment: There is no '_mess_' in the current code.  It is very happy; for around 17 lines we get a two-way Enum specific field manager.